# Turn columns into numeric, given list of columns

Tags: r

I have a list of columns, let's call them: ASSET, LIAB.

I want to turn both of them into columns. I'm using R data-table, which gives me warnings that tell me that it was converted back to character (that is, be completely useless) when I do it in a style similar to that which I would use in Python Pandas:

```
for (v in numeric_vars) {
    ris_df[, eval(v)] <- as.numeric(gsub(',', '', ris_df[, eval(v)]))
}
```

The list `numeric_vars` is the list of variables, currently string-like objects (e.g. `1,000`), which I want turned into integers.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you should use  `with=FALSE` to enable `data.frame`-like syntax to work on `data.table` objects.

```
ris_df[, eval(v), with = FALSE] <- as.numeric(gsub(',', '', ris_df[, eval(v), with = FALSE]))
```

Second, check what the output is from `gsub(',', '', dt[, eval(v), with=F])`

```
library(data.table)
test <- rep("1,000",10) 
dt <- data.table(test)
v <- "test"
dt[, v, with=FALSE] <- as.numeric(gsub(',', '', dt[, eval(v), with=F]))
> gsub(',', '', dt[, eval(v), with=F])
[1] "c(\"1000\" \"1000\" \"1000\" \"1000\" \"1000\" \"1000\" \"1000\" \"1000\" \"1000\" \"1000\")"
```

As you can see, it returns only one large string! This might be a `data.table` behaviour, since it works well for `data.frame` objects

```
df <-data.frame(dt, stringsAsFactors = F)
> as.numeric(gsub(',', '',df[, eval(v)]))
 [1] 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000 1000
```